# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression inside switch statment - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, switch-statement

I have a reducer which has switch statement but which the variable assignment inside the switch statement throughs an error ?

```
var answers, payload;
switch (action.type) {
  case ANSWER_FETCH_FAILED:
    return Object.assign({}, initialState, action.payload);
  case REMOVE_ANSWERS:
    // condition for removing the user answers  from answers

    /*line 42 */
    answers = Object.assign([], initialState.answers),

    payload = Object.assign({}, action.payload);
    // removing the deleted answer
    answers = answers.filter(ans => ans.authorId !== payload.authorId);
    // deleting the user id from payload
    delete payload.authorId;
    return Object.assign({}, initialState, { answers }, payload);
  case ANSWERED:
    /*line 50 */
    answers = Object.assign([], initialState.answers),

    payload = Object.assign({}, action.payload);
    return Object.assign({}, initialState, action.payload);
  default:
    return initialState;
}
```

Here is the error shown in the react

> ./src/reducers/postReducer.js
>
> Line 42:  Expected an assignment or
>   function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
>
> Line 50:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: after adding {} also it is showing the same error

Comment: Only use `,` when assigning to separate variables when the first assignment line has `var`, `let`, or `const` (when you're initializing *new* variables), otherwise use `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the comma `,` at the end of lines 42 and 50 with semi-colon `;`.

From

```
answers = Object.assign([], initialState.answers),
```

To

```
answers = Object.assign([], initialState.answers);
```

Comment: @Janaravi - You're welcome! Please accept the answer to close the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Just click on the check mark (✓) below the up/down vote next to the answer.